# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in starting.exe

Tags: vb.net

Sub Fill(dtable As DataTable)         Throw New NotImplementedException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in starting.exe

Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: Are your trying to call Fill(dtable)? DataAdapters have a .Fill method that takes a DataTable as an argument. Create a New DataAdapter, provide a connection and an sql statement to the data adapter and then call .Fill.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a method that explicitly throws a `NotImplementedException`, why would you be surprised to see that exception thrown when you call that method?

Throwing that exception is often the default when methods are auto-generated. The idea is that it tells you explicitly if you haven't yet implemented the body of the method rather than just doing nothing and maybe your not realising. Basically, if you're going to add a method then you need to put some code in it, so why haven't you done so for that method? If you don't want to add any code, why add the method in the first place?